# Squarespace - Custom static page "malformed data"

Tags: squarespace, static-pages

I built a small single page application as a static page. I was able to upload it and activate it on my staging site a little while ago. After uploading the code to my production site, I cannot find the static page. I checked on my staging site and it is telling me:

> This page has malformed data and can not be edited. This error has been logged. Please contact customer care if this issue persists.

Why is the page not working? I followed the instructions exactly, and it was working before, but now it doesn't even show up as an option.

---

I posted this question to [Squarespace Answers](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/194073/custom-static-page-not-showing-up.html), but I don't have much hope of getting help there, so I'm posting here also.

Comment: Show us the URL and the HTML text.

Comment: Well if I wasn't practically bald already, I could pull my hair out! Somehow the `xxx.page.conf` file got deleted from my staging site, *and* the `xxx.page` file didn't get uploaded to my production site. I uploaded the missing files, and everything works now.